# Clip a wpf Popup at bounds of a main window

Tags: wpf, popup, window, clip

From what I understand, the popup exists within it's own visual tree. However, I've noticed a few properties, Clip and ClipToBounds. What I am wanting to do is Visually clip a popup at the right and bottom edges of a window regardless of the fact that the popup is independent of the bounds of the window. I'm not using XAML, but if somebody knows how to do it in XAML, then that's fine. I can get to the main window using System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow. Is it possible from this to get a value that I can use to clip the popup? I'm assuming that if there is a value that I can use, then I would be able to bind the clipping of the popup to that value. This is really not necessary since after the popup initially opens, if the window gets moved or resized, the popup closes. So I would really only need to clip the popup when it opens. The reason I would like to do this is because although I am using a popup, I don't want it to appear as a popup that exists outside of the window. FYI this is for a popup calendar for a custom datebox. Any ideas, as well as clarification of misconceptions that I may have, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Furthermore, the popup can be launched from a user control that is not directly on the Main Window. So in that case it would be easier to use a popup. As apposed to a UC inside the XAML

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a year old post, but in case any others come here looking for answers... If you don't need the popup to be outside of your window, why use a popup at all? It'd be far easier to simply use a control in a canvas (for instance) and control it via its Visibility property. Then you'd automagically get your clipping.

Comment: I'm using a popup so that it overlays a hosted WinForm control on the WPF app. Nothing else seems to be able to overlay the Winform so popup is only option. Not being able to render the popup outside screen bounds is frustrating.

Comment: I'm using a popup because my window has a `<StackPanel>` as its content root with a `<DataGrid>` inside, there's no immediately obvious way to display a progress/activity spinner on-top of the `DataGrid` without a `Popup`.